# C++ - Defining class template (header/source file)

Tags: c++, header-files, porting, class-template

I want to create a processor in voreen (like this one [.cpp](http://voreen.uni-muenster.de/doc/4.2/curvatureanisotropicdiffusionimagefilter_8cpp_source.html) | [.h](http://voreen.uni-muenster.de/doc/4.2/curvatureanisotropicdiffusionimagefilter_8h_source.html)) porting this OTB-Application:

http://hg.orfeo-toolbox.org/OTB/file/ca4366bb972e/Applications/Segmentation/otbSegmentation.cxx

I have coded almost all the parameters into properties, etc but..

If you look at like [376](http://hg.orfeo-toolbox.org/OTB/file/ca4366bb972e/Applications/Segmentation/otbSegmentation.cxx#l376), you'll see a class template of FloatVectorImageType::SizeType, a typedef type.

Im not familiar with c++ templates so my first question was where should I put this template's implementation, in the .cpp or .h file of the processor? Taking a brief look at c++ tutorials and other processor examples like the [one above](http://voreen.uni-muenster.de/doc/4.2/curvatureanisotropicdiffusionimagefilter_8cpp_source.html), I figure out I have to declare the template in header and define it in the .cpp.

The problem is that the compiler doesnt allow me to define a template class of a typedef type inside the .cpp. The typedef isnt recognised..

So, can someone point me to the right direction here?

***segmentationprocessor.h***

```
#ifndef OTBSEGMENTATIONAPPLICATION_H
#define OTBSEGMENTATIONAPPLICATION_H

#include "otbVectorImage.h"
#include "modules/otb/ports/otbimageport.h"
#include "modules/otb/ports/otbvectorimageport.h"
#include "voreen/core/properties/boolproperty.h"

//..more includes here

namespace voreen {

class OTBSegmentationApplication : public OTBImageFilterProcessor
{
public:
    OTBSegmentationApplication();

    virtual ~OTBSegmentationApplication();

    virtual Processor* create() const;

    virtual std::string getCategory() const { return "Applications"; }
    virtual std::string getClassName() const { return "Segmentation Application"; }
    virtual CodeState getCodeState() const { return CODE_STATE_EXPERIMENTAL;}//STABLE, TESTING, EXPERIMENTAL

    virtual std::string getProcessorInfo() const;

    /** Images typedefs */
    typedef otb::VectorImage<double, 2> VectorImageType;
    typedef ImageType               LabelImageType;
    typedef ImageType               MaskImageType;

    typedef VectorImageType::SizeType size;

    // Segmentation filters typedefs
    // Edison mean-shift
    typedef otb::MeanShiftVectorImageFilter<VectorImageType,VectorImageType,LabelImageType> EdisonSegmentationFilterType;
    EdisonSegmentationFilterType::Pointer edisonFilter;

    // Home made mean-shift
    typedef otb::MeanShiftSegmentationFilter<VectorImageType, LabelImageType, VectorImageType> MeanShiftSegmentationFilterType;
    MeanShiftSegmentationFilterType::Pointer meanshiftFilter;

    // Simple connected components
    typedef otb::Functor::ConnectedComponentMuParserFunctor<VectorImageType::PixelType> FunctorType;

    typedef itk::ConnectedComponentFunctorImageFilter <VectorImageType, LabelImageType, FunctorType, MaskImageType> ConnectedComponentSegmentationFilterType;
    ConnectedComponentSegmentationFilterType::Pointer ccFilter;

    typedef itk::ScalarConnectedComponentImageFilter<LabelImageType, LabelImageType> LabeledConnectedComponentSegmentationFilterType;
    LabeledConnectedComponentSegmentationFilterType::Pointer labeledCCFilter;

    //..more typedefs here

protected:
    virtual void setDescriptions() {
        setDescription("Performs segmentation of an image, and output either a raster or a vector file. In vector mode, large input datasets are supported.");
    }
    void process();
    virtual void initialize() throw (tgt::Exception);
    virtual void deinitialize() throw (tgt::Exception);

    /** TEMPLATE DECLARATION (?) */

    template<class TInputImage, class TSegmentationFilter>
    VectorImageType::SizeType GenericApplySegmentation(otb::StreamingImageToOGRLayerSegmentationFilter
                                                       <TInputImage, TSegmentationFilter> * streamingVectorizedFilter, TInputImage * inputImage,
                                                       const otb::ogr::Layer& layer, const unsigned int outputNb);
    virtual void updateFilterSelection();
    virtual void updateModeSelection();

private:

    OTBVectorImagePort inPort_;
    StringOptionProperty filter_; ///< Select segmentation algorithm
    OTBVectorImagePort vectorOutPort_;
    OTBImagePort vectorMaskInPort_;
    OTBImagePort outPort_;

    //..more property definitions here

    static const std::string loggerCat_; ///< Category used in logging
};

} // namespace

#endif // OTBSEGMENTATIONAPPLICATION_H
```

***segmentationprocessor.cpp***

```
#include "segmentationprocessor.h"
#include "voreen/core/voreenapplication.h"

namespace voreen {

const std::string OTBSegmentationApplication::loggerCat_("voreen.OTBSegmentationApplication");

OTBSegmentationApplication::OTBSegmentationApplication()
    :OTBImageFilterProcessor(),
      inPort_(Port::INPORT, "IN Multiband Image", 0),
      vectorOutPort_(Port::OUTPORT, "OUT Multiband Image", 0),
      vectorMaskInPort_(Port::INPORT, "IN Mask Image", 0),
      outPort_(Port::OUTPORT, "OUT OTB Image", 0),

      filter_("selectFilter", "Segmentation algorithm"),

      //.. more properties code here

{
    addPort(inPort_);
    addPort(vectorOutPort_);
    addPort(vectorMaskInPort_);
    addPort(outPort_);

    addProperty(filter_);

    //.. adding the rest of properties here

    edisonFilter = EdisonSegmentationFilterType::New();
    meanshiftFilter = MeanShiftSegmentationFilterType::New();
    ccFilter = ConnectedComponentSegmentationFilterType::New();

    //..instantiating more filters needed in implementation here

}

Processor* OTBSegmentationApplication::create() const {
    return new OTBSegmentationApplication();
}

OTBSegmentationApplication::~OTBSegmentationApplication() {

}

void OTBSegmentationApplication::initialize() throw (tgt::Exception) {
    Processor::initialize();
}

void OTBSegmentationApplication::deinitialize() throw (tgt::Exception) {
    Processor::deinitialize();
}

std::string OTBSegmentationApplication::getProcessorInfo() const {
    return "Segmentation Application";
}

void OTBSegmentationApplication::updateFilterSelection() {
    //code for visual updates on properties here
}

void OTBSegmentationApplication::updateModeSelection() {
    //code for visual updates on properties here
}

    //TEMPLATE IMPLEMENTATION HERE (?)
template<class TInputImage, class TSegmentationFilter>
OTBSegmentationApplication::VectorImageType::SizeType OTBSegmentationApplication::GenericApplySegmentation(otb::StreamingImageToOGRLayerSegmentationFilter<TInputImage,
                             TSegmentationFilter> * streamingVectorizedFilter, TInputImage * inputImage, const otb::ogr::Layer& layer, const unsigned int outputNb)
    {
        typedef  TSegmentationFilter SegmentationFilterType;
        typedef  typename SegmentationFilterType::Pointer SegmentationFilterPointerType;
        typedef otb::StreamingImageToOGRLayerSegmentationFilter<TInputImage,SegmentationFilterType> StreamingVectorizedSegmentationOGRType;

    //..the rest of template code here
}


void OTBSegmentationApplication::process() {

    try
    {
        //PROCESSOR IMPLEMENTATION GOES HERE
        LINFO("Segmentation Application Connected");
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        LERROR("Error in Segmentation Applicationn");
        return;
    }
}

}   // namespace
```

> **error: ‘VectorImageType’ does not name a type (fixed)**

Comment: See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/420683); please copy any relevant code into the question. This makes it easier to understand your questions and prevents issues with broken links (in the future).

Comment: That was the first tutorial I checked, thanks. I could copy the code into the question but I'm afraid its kinda big..

Comment: Only the *relevant* parts ;) or even better [a short, but complete example](http://sscce.org) that reproduces or illustrates your problem(s)

Comment: Well the case of `CurvatureAnisotropicDiffusionImageFilterITK::curvatureAnisotropicDiffusionImageFilterITK` is certainly weird. It is protected, but defined in the .cpp That means, any derived class can only use the instantiations produced in the .cpp, which are for types `float` and `double` -- and those are *implicit* instantiations. That doesn't seem to be intentional.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant parts and copied the code skeleton above. Hope it helps..

Comment: `VectorImageType::SizeType OTBSegmentationApplication::GenericApplySegmentation` Try `OTBSegmentationApplication::VectorImageType::SizeType OTBSegmentationApplication::GenericApplySegmentation` I'll write an answer covering other issues, but this'll take some time.

Comment: Fixed the code using this, as it was my initial question. I'll put it in header for my project tho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm not familiar with c++ templates so my first question was where should I put this template's implementation, in the .cpp or .h file of the processor?

Put it in the header file. That's the simplest and most robust solution. Typically, you want to put definitions of functions (i.e. their function body) in source files (.cpp), as source files can be compiled independently. **But this isn't possible for templates**(*)**.**

<sub>(*) slightly simplified.</sub>

*Class templates* are just blueprints for classes, *function templates* are blueprints for functions. That is, *function templates are not functions*, in other words "template function" is misleading, it's not a function but a template/blueprint.

The process of building a function from a function template (or class from a class template) is called *instantiation*. The result is an instantiated function, or, more generally, a function template *specialization*.

Template specializations are *no templates*. A function template specialization is just an ordinary function with a weird name; a class template specialization is just a class with a weird name.

A template will only be instantiated for some specific sets of template arguments:

- Either if you *explicitly* ask it to be instantiated
- or if you just use a specialization (-> *implicit* instantiation).

The second way is by far the more common. An example:

```
template<class T>
struct my_type
{
    T mem;
};

// using the specialization -> implicit instantiation
my_type<int> o;
my_type<double> p;
```

This will instantiate the *class template* `my_type` once for the template argument `int`, and once for the template argument `double`. This creates two *independent* and *unrelated* types with similar names: `my_type<int>` and `my_type<double>`

And similarly for functions; except that for functions, you typically *do not explicitly provide the template arguments*. Instead, you let the compiler deduce the template arguments from the types of the function arguments. Example:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T param)
{
    std::cout << param;
}

foo<int>(42);  // explicitly specifying the template arguments -- DON'T DO THAT
foo(21);       // template argument *deduction*
```

The second call will automatically *deduce* the template argument to be `int`. Again, we have created (implicitly instantiated) two functions with similar names: `foo<int>(int)` (the name is `foo<int>` and it has a single function parameter of type `int`) and `foo<double>(double)`

---

Why it's bad to put the definitions of templates in a source file: See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/420683)

Short version: As templates are blueprints, in order to use them, the compiler has to instantiate them. But it can only instantiate what it *knows*.

If you declare a function template `foo` in a header file `templ.h`, define it in `templ.cpp` and use it in `main.cpp`, then:

- In `main.cpp`, the compiler doesn't know about the definition of the function template. It can only instantiate the *declaration* of `foo`, but not the definition.
- In `templ.cpp`, the compiler does know about the definition, and can instantiate it. However, it doesn't know about the uses outside `templ.cpp` -- therefore it cannot instantiate it for all sets of arguments used outside.

In the example in the OP, that works, but it seems to be an oversight:

[templ.h]

```
template<class T>
void foo(T);

void ordinary_function();
```

[templ.cpp]

```
#include "templ.h"

template<class T>
void foo(T p)
{
    std::cout << p;
}

void ordinary_function()
{
    foo(42);     // implicit instantiation of foo<int>
    foo(2.5);    // implicit instantiation of foo<double>
}
```

[main.cpp]

```
#include "templ.h"
int main()
{
    foo(23);    // works fine, uses the foo<int> defined in templ.cpp
    foo('a');   // linker error: foo<char> not defined
    return 0;
}
```

Because the *definition* of `foo<char>` hasn't been instantiated in `templ.cpp`, and it cannot be instantiated in `main.cpp`, this produces a linker error.

That's why you should NOT rely on this behaviour. You can use *explicit instantiation* if you, for some reason, do *not* want to define the function template in the header file. At least, the explicit instantiation is explicit, and should be documented, so that no surprises happen.

---

The problem the compiler is actually complaining about has nothing to do with templates ;) It's just a name lookup issue. A simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    typedef int Bar;

    void do_something();
};

Bar Foo::do_something()
{
    std::cout << "something\n";
}
```

When the compiler sees the line `Bar Foo::do_something()` it sees `Bar`, and cannot find what that name refers to. Hence the error. On the other hand:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    typedef int Bar;

    void do_something();
};

Foo::Bar Foo::do_something()
{
    std::cout << "something\n";
}
```

Now you told the compiler where to look for the name `Bar`, namely, inside `Foo`.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the detailed explanation! I have to admit it took me some time to understand the difference between the two approaches. The examples from voreen/ITK confused me alot, because like in my case they work either way, as you said. I'try to follow your suggestion tho.. :)

Comment: @cchantep The word "function" was right, the example below the sentence displayed *type deduction from a function call*. [quimnuss](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2111897/quimnuss) clarified that, I hope. Also, the first `>` introduces a quotation from the OP. It is also intentional.

Comment: Yep, I realised it was right but got misleaded by the writing, so I clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example on templates which I wrote in order to help you:
**in header:**

```
typedef TemplatedClassName< ParameterValue0, ParameterValue1 > TemplateAlias;
```

**in source file:**
// explicit template instantiation

```
template class TemplatedClassName< ParameterValue0, ParameterValue1 >;
```